# A function vanishing at $0$ that grows faster than the exponential

Tags: limits

Does there exist an increasing function $f$ that is continuous and vanishes at $0$ and satisfies $$f\left(\frac{1}{k}\right)e^{2k} \to 0$$ as $k \to \infty$? The common examples of modified factorials do not work since the input is supposed to take the reciprocal of $k$ instead of just $k$.

Comment: What about $f=0$ ?

Comment: Sorry, it has to be increasing. Just included it in the edit

Comment: @newbie Is my counter-example okay or do you have more conditions on $f$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $f(x)=xe^{-1/x^2}$. Then, $f$ is continuous, increasing, $f(0)=0$ and

$$\lim_{k\to\infty} f\left(\frac{1}{k}\right)e^{2k}=\lim_{k\to\infty} \frac{1}{k}e^{-k^2+2k} = 0.$$